# How to sychronously get the width and height from a base64 string of image data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3, flash, bitmapdata

Is there a way to get an image width and height from a base64 encoded image data **synchronously**? Possibly by header information.

I must make this extremely clear. I'm not interested in async methods. Please move on if you want to know reasons why async won't work. Don't even comment.

Here is my example code to encode my data. Encoding is synchronous. I'm using this [call](https://github.com/monkeypunch3/flexcapacitor/blob/master/MainLibrary/src/com/flexcapacitor/utils/DisplayObjectUtils.as#L1493):

```
var base64ImageData:String = DisplayObjectUtils.getBase64ImageDataString(displayObject, DisplayObjectUtils.PNG, null, true);
```

Here is my code to decode my data. The only method I've found in AS3 to decode is asynchronous. I'm using this [call](https://github.com/monkeypunch3/flexcapacitor/blob/master/MainLibrary/src/com/flexcapacitor/utils/DisplayObjectUtils.as#L1906):

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = DisplayObjectUtils.getBitmapDataFromBase64(bitmapDataString);
```

Let me repeat, I'm looking for a **synchronous** action. It cannot be asynchronous.

**More information:**
I'm working in ActionScript3 which is a sibling to JavaScript. If it works in JavaScript it most likely works in AS3. But I cannot work with the dom. No adding images to the dom and checking values.

**Helpful hacks:**
If it's possible to add width and height into the base64 stream and then get it later that will work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only works for png's
first thing first is to convert base64 do a buffer (Uint8array) then read the byte 16-20 (width) and 20-24 (height) as int32 value

```js
function getPngDimensions(base64) {
  let header = base64.slice(0, 50)
  let uint8 = Uint8Array.from(atob(header), c => c.charCodeAt(0))
  let dataView = new DataView(uint8.buffer, 0, 28)

  return {
    width: dataView.getInt32(16),
    height: dataView.getInt32(20)
  }
}

// Just to get some random base64 images
var random = (bottom, top) => Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom ) ) + bottom
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.width = random(10, 100)
canvas.height = random(10, 100)
console.log(`canvas width: ${canvas.width}, height: ${canvas.height}`)
var base64 = canvas.toDataURL().split(',')[1]
console.log(base64)

var dimensions = getPngDimensions(base64)
console.log(dimensions)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. If I can convert this to ActionScript3 I'll check this as the answer but it might be beyond me. AS3 has one class called ByteArray() for working with byte arrays. Documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d54.html. API Docs  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html. This is the one area where JS and AS differ and I haven't been able to decipher it all yet.

Comment: Still wondering why you are using flash :P isn't it like dead already? But sorry bro i don't know much about AS

Comment: No problem. I'll figure it out. Since you're wondering, to me Flash is like a tool set or an artists canvas. As a tool set I can get stuff done with it. As a canvas I can use it for easily creating vector or raster art and animation. The way I look at it daily is Flash or (Flex) is a tool box.

People are saying HTML5 is what all the cool kids are using, Flash is so uncool. I couldn't care less. I'm not playing keeping up with the Kardasians. I'll keep using Flex and if HTML catches up then great maybe I'll use that too. Developers are zealots for some reason. I'm just a content creator.

Comment: Where is `c` declared? What does `c => c.charCodeAt(0)` do?

Comment: @Endless _"Flash is dead"_ actually means the _Flash Player_ browser plugin. Flash [the creation tool itself] is bigger than just web-only content. Also dead is the _Java_ browser plugin but who says Java is finished (think Android apps)? Do they know that Flash compiles Android & iOS apps too?...

Comment: @1.21gigawatts `c` is a argument in a arrow function, it doesn't have to be declared. it's like writing `["a","b","c"].map(a => a.uppercase())` or `["a","b","c"].map(function(a){ return a.uppercase() }`

Comment: @Endless So in your example every item in the array is upper cased? And in your answer every ascii character is converted into it's character code?

Comment: One more question (that's a probably a lie). When you say this only works for PNG are referring to the function itself or are you saying that JPEGs do not contain size information but PNGs do?

Comment: It only works for png cuz the size information is located at byte position 16 and 20 as float value. jpeg's also has this information but it's has a different byte structure

Answer (score 2):

The following does not work but it's attempting to convert @Endless answer to AS3. I have this so far:

```
protected function windowedapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
    var base64ImageData:String = DisplayObjectUtils.getBase64ImageDataString(this, DisplayObjectUtils.PNG, null, true);
    var size:Object = getPngDimensions(base64ImageData);
}

public function getPngDimensions(base64:String):Point {
    base64 = base64.split(',')[1];
    trace(base64.length);
    base64 = base64.replace(/\n/g, "");
    trace(base64.length);
    //var header:String = base64.slice(0, 52); // 50 gave error later on
    var header:String = base64.slice(0, base64.length);
    var base64Decoder:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder();
    var byteArray:ByteArray;

    base64Decoder.reset();
    base64Decoder.decode(header);

    // base64Decoder.toByteArray(); ==>
    // Error: A partial block (2 of 4 bytes) was dropped. Decoded data is probably truncated!
    // added the whole length (52 works as well)
    byteArray = base64Decoder.toByteArray();
    byteArray.position = 0;

    //var width:String = byteArray.readUTFBytes(0);
    //var value:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    //value.readBytes(byteArray, 0, 28);
    var thing:Number = byteArray.readDouble(); // -8.091055181950927E-264
    byteArray.position = 0;
    var thing2:Number = byteArray.readFloat(); // -2.5073895107184266E-33
    byteArray.position = 0;
    var width:Number = byteArray.readFloat();
    byteArray.position = 16;
    var width:Number = byteArray.readFloat();
    byteArray.position = 20;
    var width:Number = byteArray.readFloat();
    byteArray.position = 28;
    var width:Number = byteArray.readFloat(); // 1.1074230549312416E-38
    byteArray.position = 0;
    var other:String = byteArray.readUTFBytes(byteArray.length);
    // other == "PNG\r\n\n"

    var point:Point = new Point();
    point.x = int(width);
    point.y = int(height);

    return point;
}
```

If I use `ByteArray.readUTFBytes()` I get "PNG" as a result but no width or height.

Comment: Nice (+1)...got too late to suggest this. The other thing I had in mind was very hacky and useful only if you use the .swf in the browser: Use ExternalInterface to load create an ```<img>``` element using the base64data (have the browser do the decoding for you), then read the ```.width/.height``` properties

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to avoid external interface unless there is no other way. I think if I understood ByteArrays more I could translate other answer.

Answer (score 1):

> *"If I use `ByteArray.readUTFBytes()` I get "PNG" as a result but no width or height."*

Don't read bytes as `UTF` format since that only extracts text chars. You want decimal values.

- `readDouble` and `readFloat` is too much, they read 8 bytes per action. PNG format uses only 4 bytes per width OR height value, so just read (unsigned) integers.
- Remember that every `read` action automatically moves the byteArray position. For example to know bytePos-1's value you must "walk"/read past it so you end up at bytePos-2, or for Double type you will end up at bytePos-9.

See if this re-fix of your code gets the expected values of width & height...

```
public function getPngDimensions(base64:String):Point 
{
    base64 = base64.split(',')[1];
    trace("Base64 length A : " + base64.length);
    base64 = base64.replace(/\n/g, "");
    trace("Base64 length B : " + base64.length);
    //var header:String = base64.slice(0, 52); // 50 gave error later on
    var header:String = base64.slice(0, base64.length);
    var base64Decoder:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder();
    var byteArray:ByteArray;

    base64Decoder.reset();
    base64Decoder.decode(header);

    // base64Decoder.toByteArray(); ==>
    // Error: A partial block (2 of 4 bytes) was dropped. Decoded data is probably truncated!
    // added the whole length (52 works as well)
    byteArray = base64Decoder.toByteArray();
    byteArray.position = 0;

    //# Get Width and Height values
    //# type Int is 4 bytes long so pointer auto-moves ahead by 4 bytes during Read action
    byteArray.position = 16; //start position for values...
    var width:int = byteArray.readUnsignedInt(); //reads 4 bytes, stops at Pos 20
    var height:int = byteArray.readUnsignedInt(); //reads 4 bytes, stops at Pos 24

    //# Double check (if needed)
    //trace("PNG width  : " + width);
    //trace("PNG height : " + height);

    //# Return as Point
    var point:Point = new Point();
    point.x = width; point.y = height;
    return point;
}
```

Comment: Yay! It worked! Thank you and thank for teaching me something new! If there were a way to mark two answers correct I would mark both this and @Endless answer. While the demand is probably zero StackOverflow could implement multiple answers when they pertain to different languages. So while Endless's answer was in JavaScript, your answer was in ActionScript. One answer is correct for JavaScript developers and the other for ActionScript developers.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Just put the working parts (`readInt` etc) into your own Answer & mark that as correct. My logic is, since this is an **AS3** question, myself and @Endless simply provided useful guidance towards a working solution with your own implementation.

Comment: For anyone wanting to understand more like I did, I found these two classes that show how to create a PNG and JPEG. PNG https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/images/PNGEncoder.as and JPG https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/images/JPGEncoder.as. Getting the values back out from them makes more sense now. Another class to get JPG dimensions without loading the entire file http://www.anttikupila.com/flash/getting-jpg-dimensions-with-as3-without-loading-the-entire-file/